# python socket send data from client to server

Tags: python, sockets

I am building a simple Python server than will receive data from the client and print it on screen. This is my code so far.

SERVER CODE:

```
import socket

def server(interface, port):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.bind((interface, port))
        sock.listen(1)
        print('Listening at', sock.getsockname())

        while True:
                sc, sockname = sock.accept()
                print('We have accepted a connection from', sockname)
                print(' Socket name:', sc.getsockname())
                print(' Socket peer:', sc.getpeername())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server('0.0.0.0', 8000)
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
import socket

def client(host, port):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect((host, port))
        print('Client has been assigned socket name', sock.getsockname())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client('localhost', 8000)
```

No matter how I tried to send data from the client to the server, it always errored out saying:
Transport endpoint is not connected.

Comment: Post the full traceback message. Does anything print from these programs? Which one has the error? You don't show any sends or recieves in the code. This error could happen if you `sock.recv` on the server side (that is, receive on the listen socket) instead of `sc.recv`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `127.0.0.1` or `192.168.1.X`(your private ip which you can find by using `ipconfig`in cmd) instead of localhost, this worked for me